# How to get the browser current date?

Tags: html, date

I use HTML and I want to get the user browser's **current** date. How can I do it?

I tried to use this code, but it doesn't work

```
<input type="date" name="aday" min='ateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u")'>
```

Comment: You could use javascript `new Date();` or php `date();`

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="date" min="" id="demo" />
```

you can use this in javascript.

```js
var d = new Date();
date = d.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + d.getMonth()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

now you simply need to send the `date` value to the html input tag (min attribute)
you can use

```js
document.getElementById("demo").attributes["min"] = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you cannot. No version of HTML has any concept of “getting the current date”.

What you can do is to use either server-side scripting or client-side scripting to find the current date. Note that they may return different dates, as the time zone of the server may be different from the time zone of the client.

Client-side, you can use code like the following:

```
<label for=aday>Date:</label>
<input type=date name=aday id=aday>
<script>
document.getElementById('aday').min =
  new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
</script>
```

The JavaScriopt `new Date()` yields the current date (in the client time zone, when used in client-side scripting) as a `Date` object. You need to convert it to the ISO 8601 format required by HTML5 specification. The built-in `toISOString` method helps here, but its result has additional information, which needs to be stripped off, hence the `substring` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just the best solution for catch data of client browser.

```
var todayTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had fetched this response on 19th of Oct hence the date in response (is 19) can be seen in the result. I have added the image, the input was provided in console window of chrome web browser.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript's new Date();

```
new Date();
```

Comment: It returns a date in a format that is not valid for use in a `min` attribute, so this answer is seriously incomplete, even misleading.